# GoogleTest - checkpoints

Tags: googletest

How to make by googletest checkpoints like  [BOOST_TEST_CHECKPOINT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-output/BOOST_TEST_CHECKPOINT.html)?
Thanks for any reply.

Comment: What exactly is your question ? Website youre referring to is telling you how

Comment: The question is if *Google Test* has a similar feature. The link is for how to do it with *Boost's* testing framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [`SCOPED_TRACE`](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#adding-traces-to-assertions) is what you are looking for, or at least close enough?

Comment: Thank you! This is the nearest that what I was looking.

Comment: The link is invalid. I believe here is actual one: https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#adding-traces-to-assertions

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko, ah, documentation bit rot, how do we love thee... thanks for the new location!